# Результаты сложений/вычитаний с числами float

Tags: javascript, float

Как получить результаты сложений и вычитаний с float числами, которые визуально воспринимаются нормально обычным человеком?

Например:

```
var a = 0.7;
var b = 0.1;

console.log((a*10 + b*10)/10);
```

работает как мне нужно (результат = 0.8), но если я сложу 0.295 и 0.005, то в результате получу: 0.29999999999999993. Я могу в таком случае округлять значение и написать так:

```
var a = 0.295;
var b = 0.005;

console.log(Math.round(a*10 + b*10)/10);
```

Результат будет 0.3, но в таком случае для другой пары чисел 0.003 и 9 такой код будет выполнять совсем ненужное здесь округление и вместо 9.003 показывать 9.

Я пробовал фиксировать кол-во знаков после запятой с помощью .toFixed(10); но мне не подходит такой результат, потому, что при сложении той же пары чисел 0.003 и 9 в результаты выводится еще куча ненужных нулей после цифры 3: "9.0300000000".

Подытожу. Как написать такой код, чтобы результаты сложений/вычитаний выглядели так:

```
0.7 + 0.1 = 0.8
0.295 + 0.005 = 0.3
0.003 + 9 = 9.003
1.00001 + 99 = 100.00001
0.3 - 0.005 = 0.295
```

Comment: Как правило абсолютно *все* форматы вывода не нужны. Поэтому надо просто определиться какой именно формат числа в конкретной ситуации нужен и приводить к нему. А уж как это будет решайте сами (например написать функцию, которая принимает число и нужное количество цифр после нуля)

Comment: а если я пишу калькулятор, где неизвестно что взбредет в голову пользователю, чтобы сложить/вычесть?

Comment: В общем, я пока не понял адское ли это извращение или единственное решение моей проблемы, но если, как в первом примере, умножать оба числа на 10 000 000 000(т.к. мне нужно 10 знаков после запятой) и затем их сумму делить на это же число, то все примеры работают так, как мне нужно.

Comment: @C01 скорее извращение. С таким подходом долго ждать Infinity не придется.

Comment: @C01 ну ок,  в данном случае, при написании калькулятора можно делать `toFixed`. И так как этот метод возвращает строку, то напиши функцию, которая обрезает нули на конце и всё. Банально это просто сделать регуляркой.

Comment: [ТЫК](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round). На этом сайте Mozzila есть подробное объяснение как делать округление чиесл с плавающей точкой.

Answer (score 2):

Надеюсь это поможет. Использую такое округление во всех своих проектах.

```
function round(value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
}

round(0.7 + 0.1, 2) // 0.8
round(0.003 + 9, 4) // 9.003
round(0.3 - 0.005, 4) // 0.295
```