# Сумма чисел с плавающей точкой

Tags: javascript, числа

Пытаясь посчитать сумму чисел заметил следующее поведение:
 
`0.7 + 0.2 + 0.1 = 0.99999999...`
Почему так происходит понятно из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417454/192182).

Что с этим делать, если нужно чтобы ответ получался правильным?
 В данном случае: `0.7 + 0.2 + 0.1 = 1`
Какие есть решения данной проблемы?

Comment: например, округлять при преобразовании числа в строку, используя [`.toFixed(число_знаков_после_запятой)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: @diraria а если не знаешь числа? например делаешь калькулятор? Я даже сейчас найду вопрос, где о таком спрашивалось, но ответов там никто не дал .......... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/735793/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот неправда, там есть [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735793/Результаты-сложений-вычитаний-с-числами-float#comment1120764_735793) подходящий под условия автора

Comment: Используйте что-то вроде этого https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/. Я как-то пилил калькулятор и каждое число представлял обычной дробью - там числитель и знаменатель целые. А после всех действий с ними делил числитель на знаменатель и выводил.

Comment: @diraria не правда, там обязательно указывать `decimals`, что опять же, при вычислениях "на лету" - бесполезно

Comment: @selya  `каждое число представлял обычной дробью - там числитель и знаменатель целые` - и как, получалось? А то  `var test = 2/10 + 1/10;
console.log(test);` выведет ответом `0.30000000000000004` ..... а `var test = 7/10 + 2/10 + 1/10;
console.log(test);` соответственно всё также `0.9999999999999999`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А вы меня неправильно поняли. Каждое число - объект, в нем целочисленный числитель и знаменатель. При сложении приводим к общему знаменателю, складываем, сокращаем дробь. И так проделываем все операции, а делим дробь лишь для того, чтобы получить представление в виде десятичной

Comment: @selya просто про "При сложении приводим к общему знаменателю" - не было речи %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я счел это логичным и очевидным)

Comment: Два варианта. 

1. Округлить полученный ответ.

либо

2. Использовать тип BigDecimal.

Я собаку на этом съел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибку вычисления избежать трудно (много танцев с числами).

Лучше будет округлять после вычисления. 
причем можно округлять до целых если мы хотим видеть только целое число.

```
Math.round
```

Но если мы ожидаем увидеть дробное число этот метод не подойдет нужно использовать округление до до разумного знака после запятой. Округления до 10-го знака обычно бывает достаточно, чтобы отсечь ошибку вычислений и при этом получить нужную точность вычислений:

```
(0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(10)
```

но тут мы получаем тип **string** нужно доработать с помощью

```
parseFloat
```

Резюмируя округление можно делать так:

```
parseFloat((0.1 + 0.2+0.7).toFixed(10));
```

Comment: Неплохой вариант. Наверное в большинстве случаев сработает. Хотя если будет требование иметь возможность большое количество знаков после запятой, то `parseFloat((0.2+0.1).toFixed(17));` выдаст `0.30000000000000004` %)  ...... но в целом - норм

Answer (score 1):

Все числа умножить на 10, округлить и просуммировать. Затем результат разделить на 10:

```
(Math.round(n1*10) + Math.round(n2*10) + ... + Math.round(nn*10)) / 10
```

Comment: Любое всякое можно отсечь....

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/223613)

Comment: если вопрос простой, то и ответ на него очевидно тоже должен быть простым, и если для Вас мой ответ по всей видимости в силу простоты не имеет ценности - для автора вопроса ценность может оказаться ощутимой, так как поможет ему лучше понять среду в которой он программирует ))