# Плавающая точка (float числа) IEEE-754 как пофикси?

Tags: javascript, ieee-754

Как избавится от проблем формата IEEE-754, который создаёт проблемы с записью числа:

```
4.3-3=1.2999999999999998

0.1+0.2=0.30000000000000004
```

Как мне избавится от этих проблем?

Comment: А в чём, собственно, проблема? Для вывода результатов нужно использовать форматирование, для сравнения использовать допустимую погрешность. В каких-то случаях можно использовать целые числа вместо вещественных.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сумма чисел с плавающей точкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762832/%d0%a1%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 2):

Никаких проблем нет:

1. Для вывода результатов нужно использовать форматирование.
2. Для сравнения использовать допустимую погрешность.
3. Для денег использовать специальный тип.
4. В каких-то случаях можно использовать целые числа вместо вещественных.

Answer (score -1):

Я бы лично для таких ситуаций просто использовал числа по больше, вот пример:

```js
class CorrectFloat {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = +x || 0
  }

  increase(y) {
    return correctFloat(((this.x * 1e3) + (y * 1e3)) / 1e3)
  }

  decrease(y) {
    return correctFloat(((this.x * 1e3) - (y * 1e3)) / 1e3)
  }

  get() {
    return this.x
  }
}

function correctFloat(n) {
  return new CorrectFloat(n)
}

console.log('0.1 + 0.2 =', correctFloat(0.1)
  .increase(0.2)
  .get()
)

console.log('4.3 - 3 =', correctFloat(4.3)
  .decrease(3)
  .get()
)
```

Конечно с такими числами могут возникнуть проблемы, для примера, если число будет слишком большим, то тогда оно (число) не измениться вообще, но для таких ситуаций можно использовать `BigInt`, нужно будет создавать отдельный класс и функцию под это. Но если работать с не большими числами то всё будет работать вполне нормально. (Ну и где по меньше чисел после запятой :), в смысле после точки)